# Difference in printing private and shared array in OpenMP

Tags: fortran, openmp

I am using an array and printing it from three threads. The options I have chosen for the array is declaring it as private and shared.

1. The array is declared private with OpenMP clause. The code is

```
program test
  use omp_lib
  implicit none

  integer,  dimension(6) :: x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  integer :: i

  !$omp parallel private (x) num_threads(3)
  !$omp do

  do i = 1,6
     x(i) = x(i) + i
     print*, x(i)  , 'from thread = ', omp_get_thread_num ()
  end do

  !$omp end do
  !$omp end parallel


end program test
```

**The output** I get is (it changes for each run)

```
           1 from thread =            0
           2 from thread =            0
  1407186565 from thread =            2
         210 from thread =            2
  1411382163 from thread =            1
         208 from thread =            1
```

2. For the same code with the shared clause of the array x, I get the expected output

```
program test
  use omp_lib
  implicit none

  integer,  dimension(6) :: x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  integer :: i

  !$omp parallel shared (x) num_threads(3)
  !$omp do

  do i = 1,6
     x(i) = x(i) + i
     print*, x(i)  , 'from thread = ', omp_get_thread_num ()
  end do

  !$omp end do
  !$omp end parallel


end program test
```

**The output**

```
           2 from thread =            0
           4 from thread =            0
          10 from thread =            2
          12 from thread =            2
           6 from thread =            1
           8 from thread =            1
```

So, if the array is declared private, is it not possible to update it privately for the respective indices?

The program is run with gfortran using command

```
gfortran main.f90 -fopenmp
```

Comment: The answer is the first sentence of the linked accepted answer: *"private variables are not initialised, i.e. they start with random values..."*. The solution using firstprivate is also shown there.